# Swing GUI Builder Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I can't seem to run a form on IntelliJ GUI builder

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null.
```

I assume the code to initialize the views are auto generated. Right now I only have a `JPanel` and somehow it is not auto-initialized even thought it's clearly visible on the designer.

It's a Gradle project and I've chosen to run with the generated main function.

What do I have to do to get it working?

```
public class MyForm {

    private JPanel jPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyForm");
        frame.setContentPane(new MyForm().jPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you compiling your project?

Comment: @yole 
It's a gradle project and I've chosen to run with the generated main function.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've added more details

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default, the IntelliJ IDEA UI designer works by generating bytecode, which is unfortunately not supported with Gradle builds. You can change it to generate source code in Settings | Editor | GUI Designer.

Comment: This worked, but doing a gradle rebuild didn't fix it right away until I had specifically right clicked on the Forms Java file and selected recompile.

Comment: I had the same problem with Gradle but this answer did not solve it, even after rebuilding the Form separately.  I ended up converting the project to Maven and now it compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 3):

see [Intellij (Swing) GUI not compiling because of Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844177/intellij-swing-gui-not-compiling-because-of-gradle)

solved by changing intellij settings (also see the screenshot)

i've checked:

- automaticaly import ...
- build and run using - set - intellij
- run tests using - set - intellij
- Gradle JVM - set - Use project JDK