# Intellij (Swing) GUI not compiling because of Gradle

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Gradle project and I am trying to create a GUI (Swing, using Intellij); however, I keep receiving an error on compile. The exact same GUI code can be run on a standard Java project and compiles fine.

GUI

```
package gui;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ApplicationGUI {
    private JPanel rootPanel;
    private JLabel testLabel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ApplicationGUI");
        frame.setContentPane(new ApplicationGUI().rootPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile 'ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-base:3.7.0'
    compile 'ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-structures-dstu3:3.7.0'
    compile 'ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-client:3.7.0'
}
```

Error

> Task :ApplicationGUI.main() FAILED
>       Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null.
>       at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:621)
>       at javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPane(JFrame.java:698)
>       at gui.ApplicationGUI.main(ApplicationGUI.java:11)

In my settings I have the GUI Designer set to Java Source Code.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

EDIT1:

I can confirm that the above code works 100% fine with Maven..

Comment: This has nothing to do with gradle, `rootPanel` is `null`, and you can't set a `null`  value as the content pane .

Comment: Well I don't have to set anything in my other project without Gradle? When I initialise it I don't have any of my GUI components? As in, they are not present/visible on the form.

Comment: please find a solution [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185378/intellij-idea-13-ui-designer-and-automatic-gradle-building) !

Answer (score 20):

Solved by changing intellij settings:

I've checked:

- automatically import ...
- build and run using - set - intellij
- run tests using - set - intellij
- Gradle JVM - set - Use project JDK

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ]

My code was:

```
package com.mygdx.game.desktop;

import javax.swing.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglAWTCanvas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class MainForm {
    private JPanel mainpanel_1;
    private JPanel visualizationPanel_1;
    private JButton button1;

    private static MyGdxGame visualization;
    private JFrame mainFrame;

    public MainForm(JFrame frame) {
        mainFrame = frame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("My First Swing Example");
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1300, 850));
            frame.setSize(1300, 850);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            MainForm mf = new MainForm(frame);
            if(mf.mainpanel_1 != null) {
                frame.setContentPane(mf.mainpanel_1);
            }

            visualization = new MyGdxGame();

            LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
            config.width = 1200;
            config.height = 800;
            config.forceExit = false;
            config.resizable = false;
            LwjglAWTCanvas lwjglCanvas = new LwjglAWTCanvas(visualization, config);
            mf.visualizationPanel_1.add(lwjglCanvas.getCanvas());

            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                    lwjglCanvas.stop();
                    System.exit(0);
                }


            });

            frame.pack();

            // Setting the frame visibility to true
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change execution from Gradle to Intellij won't fix the main problem because it will keep not working when the Gradle jar were built.

I did the following to fix the problem and keep using Gradle.

Into `Editor -> GUI Designer -> Generate GUI into`, Choose **Java Source**

[image]

add Intellij forms dependency to your gradle project

```
implementation 'com.intellij:forms_rt:7.0.3'
```

Go the the GUI for editor and do some change (like create a new component or change a label) this way Intellij will generate the necessary code.

Run the main class

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue between Gradle and Intellij. A solution is to migrate to Maven. The `.form` file (generated by Intellij) for the GUI should be initialised at the line `frame.setContentPane(new ApplicationGUI().rootPanel);` but this does not happen. There are no issues when using Maven.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments, your rootPanel is never initialized thus it's null. 
JFrame has a jpanel contentPane already by default so you don't really need the below line, unless you intend to replace it :

```
frame.setContentPane(new ApplicationGUI().rootPanel);
```

> public void setContentPane(Container contentPane)
>
> Sets the contentPane property.This method is called by the
>   constructor.  Swing's painting architecture requires an opaque
>   JComponentin the containment hiearchy. This is typically provided by
>   thecontent pane. If you replace the content pane it is recommended
>   youreplace it with an opaque JComponent.

Below's some sample code creating a frame and adding a label to it.

```
public class ApplicationGUI{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("some text");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ApplicationGUI");
        frame.getContentPane().add(aLabel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so this lets the GUI be shown but none of the contents are visible?

Comment: Also, how is the rootPanel null? Doesn't the `new` keyword sort that out?

Comment: _none of the contents are visible_ : because you didn't add any contents to your JFrame.
_Doesn't the new keyword sort that out_ : No because it's called on your class ApplicationGUI, and not on its instance variable rootPanel. To initialize it you can do `private JPanel rootPanel = new JPanel();`

Comment: Okay so how do I add them to the JFrame? `frame.add(testLabel)` doesn't work because it doesn't recognise `testLabel`. Also I tried to initialise the JPanel like that but nothing changed.

Comment: Okay so that works, but I have an `ApplicationGUI.form` file with all of my elements inside it. How would I attach this file or at least include all of its elements in their correct position?

Comment: I am not familiar with IntelliJ, please read some tutorials on how to load .form files